# What does "wife on the crupper" mean in Hunchback of Notre Dame?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> Comrades! Master Simon Sanguin, the Elector of Picardy, with his wife on the crupper!

Chapter 1 of Hugo, Victor. The Hunchback of Notre-Dame (AmazonClassics Edition) (p. 25). AmazonClassics. Kindle Edition.

Comment: Did you try looking up "crupper" in the dictionary?

Comment: @Barmar It's the first thing I did, but didn't help me a single bit. Weirdly enough, it made it more confusing due to the paragraph not mentioning horses, but them on foot.

Comment: FYI, if you need to ask questions about the meaning *in context* of phrases from stories, rather than just direct meaning of English words like this question, there's also [literature.se] SE.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks! Wasn't aware of that one.

Answer (score 23):

When you hear *crupper*, think *rear end* or *back*, especially of a horse.

In this passage (found in [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2610/2610-h/2610-h.htm)), a group of students is sarcastically greeting the rector and dignitaries of their university. As the first greetings show, they usually focus on whatever they can mock:

> “Good day, monsieur le recteur! Holà hé! good day there!”
>
> “How does he manage to be here, the old gambler? Has he abandoned his dice?”
>
> “How he trots along on his mule! her ears are not so long as his!”

Toward the end of the procession, we have the sequence that you quoted:

> “Comrades! Master Simon Sanguin, the Elector of Picardy, with his wife on the crupper!”
>
> “*Post equitem sedet atra cura*—behind the horseman sits black care.”
>
> “Courage, Master Simon!”
>
> “Good day, Mister Elector!”
>
> “Good night, Madame Electress!”

A *crupper* is the back or butt of the horse ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crupper)). To verify, we can look at the French, which uses the cognate *croupe*:

> —Camarades! maître Simon Sanguin, l'électeur de Picardie, qui a sa femme en croupe.

*En croupe* can be seen in this print by Stefano Della Bella, titled *Deux cavaliers, tenant chacun **une femme en croupe**, font boire leurs chevaux dans une rivière* [Two knights, each carrying **a woman on the horse-rump**, let their horses drink in the river], where two women ride on horses behind the knight "en croupe," or on the butt/back ([New York Public Library](https://digitalcollections.nypl.org/items/0c8f8470-2fc9-0133-5770-58d385a7b928)):

[image]

Here is a better image from the same printer (*Un cavalier avec une dame en croupe derrière lui* [A knight with a lady on the horse-rump behind him], [Limédia Galeries](https://galeries.limedia.fr/ark:/79345/d7fdzflgsvnhptj5/)):

[image]

Presumably Master Sanguin's lady also sits similarly *en croupe*, or *on the crupper*.

To return to the quote with the fuller context, the point of mockery here isn't about *crupper* at all. Instead, the jeers focus on the appearance of the wife, who is called *atra cura* - "black care." The joke may be that she causes him trouble ("Courage, Master Simon!").

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I'm reading the book now and it had me stumped. Makes it so much easier to understand the whole section.

Answer (score 1):

In the medieval times in which Victor Hugo set *The Hunchback of Notre-Dame*, a crupper was a piece of “horsewear” — if you will.

Without further research into the context of this work, I can’t say if that refers to the back end “seat belt” that secures the saddle to horse, or the full butt armor that protects it.

Have a look around at [`medieval crupper`](https://www.google.com/search?q=medieval+crupper&tbm=isch) and come back here if you think this angle is worth exploring further.